# mysql Get missing values

Tags: mysql, insert, left-join

I know this is ordinary question but I need something more. I have an issue about getting values that are not inserted in one table.

Ok here are my tables:

1. name: importantDates; cols: id, date
2. name: inserts; cols: id, date, employe_id

My question: how to get missing values for each employe? Let's say I need missing inserts from employe with id=213?

So far, I wrote this, but it doesn't work yet as if there is insert for one worker in one day, it eliminates one day for all workers.

code:

```
SELECT i.date 
FROM importantDates i 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN inserts s 
        ON i.date = DATE(s.date) 
WHERE i.date BETWEEN '2013-1-1' 
    AND '2013-2-23' 
   AND s.date IS NULL;
```

Now how can I add checking for employe_id?

Thanks guys, if you need anything more I'm always available.

EDIT:
Here is sample:
Employe:
1. sam
2. mike
3. joe
importantDate:
1. 2013-01-01
2. 2013-01-02
3. ...
40. 2013-02-23
inserts:
1. 2013-02-01, 1 
2. 2013-02-01, 2
3. 2013-02-01, 3
4. 2013-02-02, 3
5. 2013-02-03, 1
6. 2013-02-03, 2
7. 2013-01-12, 1

So, when I run query, I should get all "missing" inserts. For each employe I should get date and ID of employee when insert is missing. A lot of data but it is important to know which are not inserted and which are.

Comment: OK, I edited my question. Right answer is already given but in case I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have an `employee` table, try:

```
select sq.* from
(select e.employe_id, i.date
 FROM importantDates i
 CROSS JOIN employee e
 WHERE i.date BETWEEN '2013-1-1' AND '2013-2-23') sq
LEFT OUTER JOIN inserts s 
  ON sq.date = DATE(s.date) and sq.employe_id = s.employe_id
WHERE s.date IS NULL;
```

If you don't have a separate `employee` table, you can simulate one by changing `employee` in the above query to be:

```
(select distinct employe_id from inserts) as e
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Can you tell me where did you get this or have you written it by yourself now? Because I haven't find this example anywhere. Oh, and I have seperate "employe" table :)

Comment: @Matjaz: I worked it out myself, based on the requirements you described. :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN use a simple LEFT JOIN and provide the dates correctly

```
SELECT
  i.date
FROM importantDates i
  LEFT JOIN inserts s
    ON i.date = DATE(s.date)
WHERE i.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01'
    AND '2013-02-23'
    AND s.date IS NULL;
```

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN is the same as LEFT JOIN - the OUTER keyword is optional.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I understand, what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to get every row from `table_a` which is not in `table_b` you can do this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a 
WHERE table_a.col NOT IN 
( 
    SELECT col FROM table_b
)
```

So (if I understand you correctly) in your case:

```
SELECT i.date FROM importantDates i 
WHERE i.date NOT IN 
(
    SELECT date FROM inserts WHERE employe_id = 213
) 
AND i.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-23';
```

For more documentation to the `IN`-clause see [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

**UPDATE:**

To get the corresponding employee you ***can*** alter the statement to this:

```
SELECT i.date, e.* FROM importantDates i 
JOIN employees e
WHERE i.date NOT IN 
(
    SELECT s.date FROM inserts s WHERE s.employe_id = e.employe_id
) 
AND i.date BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-02-23';
```

However, this is ***not*** recommendable because the subquery is [correlated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) to the mainquery.

Comment: Hey, no you didn't understand me correctly. I already have this, I just need to add one more condition to search for each "employe_id" for every day. But thanks for answer anyway, it is another way of getting values that are not inserted yet.

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted to get a specific employee by id. I updated my answer, though I don't recommend to use it. In this case Mark Bannister's answer might be the best approach.